# ObjC - Write To MyApp.app folder (iOS 7)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

For some reason, my reading of text files doesn't work unless I go in the MyApp.app directory, but then it works.

All the tutorials I find only cover writing to the documents folder, how can I write to the 'MyApp.app' folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write directly to the app bundle directory from your app. It is read-only by design.

You are also highly constrained as to where else you can read and write from/to.

The following document provides more information about how the file system works in iOS, including read/write permissions and the conventions that you should follow:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html